# OpenGL: Can not write to framebuffer

Tags: c++, opengl

I've been struggling with this for a while, without any positive result. I've also implemented framebuffers with multiple render targets before, without any issues, but right now it wont work for some reason.

Here's the code for initialization:

```
   // LOAD TEXTURE 1
        glGenTextures(1, &m_Texture1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_Texture1);
        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, size.x, size.y, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

        // LOAD TEXTURE 2
        glGenTextures(1, &m_Texture2);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_Texture2);
        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB16F, size.x, size.y, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, NULL);


        // LOAD TEXTURE 3
        glGenTextures(1, &m_Texture3);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_Texture3);
        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB32F_ARB, size.x, size.y, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, NULL);



        // Load FBO
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_fbo);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, m_fbo);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_Texture1, 0);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_Texture2, 0);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_Texture3, 0);

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
```

And for drawing:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, m_fbo);

        /// Draw the buffers, 3 color textures
        GLenum buffers[] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2_EXT };
        glDrawBuffers(3, buffers);

        /// Clear all the buffers
        GLfloat color1[] = { 1.0f, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
        GLfloat color2[] = { 0.0f, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
        GLfloat color3[] = { 0.0f, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, color1);
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 1, color2);
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 2, color3);

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
```

I'm using gDEBugger for debugging buffers etc, and the 3 textures should be yellow, green and blue if i'm not right? But they are black for some reason...

Comment: Oh god damn, I managed to fix it. Here's the error:
#define glClearBufferfv __glClearBufferfv;
#define glDrawBuffers __glDrawBuffers;

The ";" made the compiled ignore the function call.

Comment: The error seems to be those underscores, if I'm being honest. Are you battling with some incorrect calling convention / name mangling problems?

Comment: Underscores at the beginning of variabler is ok. It were the ; after the define that messed up the code.